# Simultaneously writing and validating XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd

I have a Write method that serializes objects which use XmlAttributes. It's pretty standard like so:

```
private bool WriteXml(DirectoryInfo dir)
{
    var xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof (Composite));
    _filename = Path.Combine(dir.FullName, _composite.Symbol + ".xml");
    using (var xmlFile = File.Create(_filename))
    {
          xml.Serialize(xmlFile, _composite);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Apart from trying to read the file I have just written out (with a Schema validator), can I perform XSD validation WHILE the XML is being written?

I can mess around with memory streams before writing it to disk, but it seems in .Net there is usually an elegant way of solving most problems.

Comment: Don't put tags in the title of your question.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles for more info.

Comment: Doesn't the XML Serializer already produce compliant XML?  What would be the point of checking it again?

Comment: Against an XSD that is shared among different parts of the business. I want to know if I change something in my code, I am not breaking the XSD rules.

Comment: So, really, it's an automated integration test, which you only have to run once against the generated XML when the code changes.

Comment: Partially yes, howveer there are restriction inside the XSD, say regex on certain strings etc. I would rather not duplicate these check in code, esp since the XSD may change in the future. Unless someone always remembers to check the code, it may fail. That would not be so bad, except I need to know straight away if the failure has occured, not sometime later when someone else reads it.

Comment: That's a pretty hefty performance penalty to check it each and every time it is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I've done it is like this for anyone interested:

```
public Composite Read(Stream stream)
{
    _errors = null;
    var settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(XmlComponentsXsd))
    {
        using (var schemaReader = new XmlTextReader(fileStream))
        {
            settings.Schemas.Add(null, schemaReader);
            settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
            settings.ValidationEventHandler += OnValidationEventHandler;
            using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stream, settings))
            {
                var serialiser = new XmlSerializer(typeof (Composite));
                return (Composite) serialiser.Deserialize(xmlReader);
            }
        }
    }
}

private ValidationEventArgs _errors = null;
private void OnValidationEventHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs validationEventArgs)
{
    _errors = validationEventArgs;
}
```

Then instead of writing the XML to file, using a memory stream do something like:

```
private bool WriteXml(DirectoryInfo dir)
{
    var xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof (Composite));
    var filename = Path.Combine(dir.FullName, _composite.Symbol + ".xml");
    // first write it to memory
    var memStream = new MemoryStream();
    xml.Serialize(memStream, _composite);
    memStream.Position = 0;
    Read(memStream);
    if (_errors != null)
    {
        throw new Exception(string.Format("Error writing to {0}. XSD validation failed : {1}", filename, _errors.Message));
    }
    memStream.Position = 0;
    using (var outFile = File.OpenWrite(filename))
    {
        memStream.CopyTo(outFile);
    }
    memStream.Dispose();
    return true;
}
```

That way you're always validating against the schema before anything is written to disk.